# Power automate notification during work hours

Tags: power-automate

I am using simple template to recieve notification on mobile, upon mail arrives (mail arrives to specific folder) > notification with simple headline and subject of email.

I would like to tune it to recieve the notification only from 8:00 - 16:00 and thats it.
I am playing with start of hour: startOfHour()

But so far struggle to define the condition properly.

Regards,
V.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create a scheduled query every hour and then create a condition that will only run if it is a certain time like in the picture example.

```
@{startOfHour(convertFromUtc(UTCNow(),'Eastern Standard Time', 't'), 't')}
```

[image: Flow]

Comment: But this would eliminate the "Upon mail arrival" notification right?
Thought of this and this might be part to solve it, i was thinking of expanding this to a Range instead of hour?

Comment: You still can use your "Upon mail arrival." It will still run everytime, but if you do a Condition statement, it will only run the logic you need to at certain times.